# Display Message when <video> is finished

Tags: javascript, html5-video

This might have been answered before but I have searched for hours and can't find anything without jquery on getting this to work and I don't really understand the bind method or how that works.

I just need my video to display a message once it is finished.
For some reason any time I try to use video.ended I get null back instead of true or false.
Also not sure why my setInterval is apparently wrong.

HTML:

```
<video id="videoAllUrBase" poster="images/all-ur-base-poster.png">
    <source src="video/All Your Base Are Belong To Us.mp4" />
    <source src="video/All Your Base Are Belong To Us.mp4.ogg" />
    <source src="video/All Your Base Are Belong To Us.mp4.webm" />
    <p>Your browsers does not support video</p>
</video>
<br></br>
<input id="playButton" type="button" onclick="playVideo();" value="Play" />
<input id="skipButton" type="button" onclick="skip(10);" value="Skip" />
<input id="rewButton" type="button" onclick="skip(-10);" value="Rewind" />
<p id="vidMessage">Click the Play button to start the video.</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function playVideo(){
    var video = document.getElementById('videoAllUrBase');
    var message = document.getElementById('vidMessage');
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton');

    if(video.paused){
        video.play();
        button.value = "Pause";
        message.innerHTML = "The video is playing, click the Pause button to pause the video.";
    } else {    
        video.pause();
        button.value = "Play";
        message.innerHTML = "The video is paused, click the Play button to resume the video.";
    } 

}

function checkEnd{
    var video = document.getElementById('videoAllUrBase');
    var message = document.getElementById('vidMessage');

    if(video.ended){
        message.innerHTML = "The video has ended, click Play to restart the video.";
    }
}

setInterval(checkEnd, 1000);

function skip(value) {
    var video = document.getElementById("videoAllUrBase");
    video.currentTime += value;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using setInterval to check, just use the "onended" event to know when it ends.

Comment: Finally got it to work using:

  video.onended = function(e) {
   message.innerHTML = "FINALLY THE END!";  
  }

Comment: Glad you got it working; I added an answer with that suggestion and how I'd set it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setInterval` to check for the video's status, listen for the `ended` event to know when it ends. Here's your code with the changes I'd use:

```
function playVideo() {
    var video = document.getElementById('videoAllUrBase');
    var message = document.getElementById('vidMessage');
    var button = document.getElementById('playButton');

    if (video.paused) {
        video.play();
        button.value = "Pause";
        message.innerHTML = "The video is playing, click the Pause button to pause the video.";
    } else {    
        video.pause();
        button.value = "Play";
        message.innerHTML = "The video is paused, click the Play button to resume the video.";
    }

    video.onended = videoEnded;
}

function videoEnded() {
    var video = document.getElementById('videoAllUrBase');
    var message = document.getElementById('vidMessage');
    message.innerHTML = "The video has ended, click Play to restart the video.";
}

function skip(value) {
    var video = document.getElementById("videoAllUrBase");
    video.currentTime += value;
}
```

While it probably wouldn't affect your setup, it could be more useful to use `addEventListener` to bind the event.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Media_events
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener